# View with wrong height (same as parent)

Tags: objective-c

I extended the `UIView` class to create an overlay load screen.

---

FullLoadingView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FullLoadingView : UIView

+ (instancetype)showOnView:(UIView *)view;
+ (void)hideAll:(UIView *)view;

- (void)hide;

@end
```

---

FullLoadingView.m

```
#import "FullLoadingView.h"

@implementation FullLoadingView

+ (instancetype)showOnView:(UIView *)view
{
    FullLoadingView *fullLoadingView = [[self alloc] init];
    [fullLoadingView setFrame:view.bounds];
    [fullLoadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(250.0/255.0) green:(250.0/255.0) blue:(250.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicatorView.center = fullLoadingView.center;
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    [view addSubview:fullLoadingView];

    return fullLoadingView;
}

- (void)hide
{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

+ (void)hideAll:(UIView *)view
{
    NSEnumerator *subviewsEnum = [view.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];
    for (UIView *subview in subviewsEnum) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:self]) {
            FullLoadingView *fullLoadingView = (FullLoadingView *)subview;
            [fullLoadingView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

---

*UIViewController code:*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    FullLoadingView *fullLoadingView = [FullLoadingView showOnView:self.view];
}
```

**Issue:**
When the `UIViewController` has `NavigationBar` or `TabBar` the central alignment of the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is not correct.

PS: The `self.view` has the correct height (excluding`NavigationBar` or `TabBar`) but`FullLoadingView` always has full height of the device.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating `fullLoadingView` in `viewDidLoad`, but `self.view`'s frame is not guaranteed to be correct for the current device until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Probably the simplest fix is to use `autoresizingMask` to keep the frames in sync:

```
+ (instancetype)showOnView:(UIView *)view
{
    FullLoadingView *fullLoadingView = [[self alloc] init];
    fullLoadingView.frame = view.bounds;
    fullLoadingView.autoresizingMask = (
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
        | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    fullLoadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(250.0/255.0) green:(250.0/255.0) blue:(250.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicatorView.center = fullLoadingView.center;
    activityIndicatorView.autoresizingMask = (
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
        | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
        | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
        | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
    [fullLoadingView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    [view addSubview:fullLoadingView];

    return fullLoadingView;
}
```